# grep something from a file using system or grep

Tags: perl, variables, grep

I have some code here. But I don't think it's working.

```
 my $answer = grep (/$A'\t'$B/, $file);
```

Alternatively I tried

```
 my $answer = system( "grep $A'\t'$B, $file);
```

The first one doesn't print anything, and the second one prints out the actual grepped line to the console. However, $answer remains

My goal is grep lines out of a file. I know there should only be 1 match. I would like to save the line from $file that matches the "$A\t$B" to the variable $answer. I was wondering how I would do that without reading the whole file in. But if I read line by line, I think that would be inefficient time-wise, because here I will be doing that multiple times. I'm afraid of memory issues if I read the entire file in.

Any thoughts?

Comment: File::Grep CPAN module may helps you a lot.

Comment: "But if I read line by line, I think that would be inefficient time-wise". What do you think /usr/bin/grep does when it searches a file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using backticks:

```
my $answer = `grep $A'\t'$B $file`;
```